# Question tag in colloquial English

Tags: tag-questions

Can I skip the questioning part in a question tag sentence, for example, instead of saying

> Oh, you have watched it, haven't you?

to

> Oh, you have watched it?

with a high raising pitch in the end to make it as a question or a wondering expression and skip the "haven't you" part completely.

Is the ok in colloquial English?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is okay (in general - colloquial).

But take note that it's not usually referred to as 'pitch'. (Linguistics, see this wikipedia entry [here](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intonation_(linguistics))):

> The classic example of intonation is the question-statement distinction. For example, northeastern American English, like very many languages (Hirst & DiCristo, eds. 1998), has a rising intonation for echo or declarative questions (He found it on the street?), and a falling intonation for wh- questions (Where did he find it?) and statements (He found it on the street.). Yes or no questions (Did he find it on the street?) often have a rising end, but not always. Some languages like Chikasaw and kalaallisut have the opposite pattern: rising for statements and falling with questions.

It's '[intonation](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/intonation)'.